# Why is one of my user's authorities being ignored?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to understand how to secure my SB 3.1 REST services with Spring Sec 6 for the following authentication/authorisation use case.   I do have authentication working but Method security has an issue in that although an authority is present on the authentication, hasAuthority is I suppose returning false.

I have a /signin REST controller that takes a name and password, posts to a remote Auth service, and on successful remote auth, I want to create a Jwt with the user's authorities and return that as an accessToken in the response to /signin.  I have this service working fine (I think).  I don't need (I don't think) to tell the SecurityConfig about this (apart from permitAll() on /signin) : the Authentication process will either see the Jwt and be able to decode it, or it wont.

For all requests that require authentication I extract the token, decode it and create an authentication for the user with the authority list.   But although I can see the authority in the list (it is the last one) when i parse the claims from the jwt:

```
{sub=maryia, permissions=[SFG_UI_SCT_ENTITY_TRANSMIT, FB_UI_TRUSTED_CERTS_NEW, SFG_UI_SCT_CREATE_ENTITY_GPL, SFG_UI_SCT_CREATE_ENTITY_SCT, FB_UI_TRUSTED_CERTS_APPROVE, FB_UI_TRUSTED_CERTS, SFG_UI_HOME, SFG_UI_SCT_APPROVE_ENTITY_SCT, SFG_UI_SCT_APPROVE_ENTITY_GPL, SFG_UI_SCT_EDIT_ENTITY_SCT, SFG_UI_SCT_EDIT_ENTITY_GPL, SFG_SCT_ICFOutbound, SFG_UI_SCT_DELETE_ENTITY_GPL, SFG_UI_SCT_DELETE_ENTITY_SCT, SFG_UI_SCT_ENTITY, FB_UI_TRUSTED_CERTS_DELETE]
```

my method does allow access on that final authority:

```
 @DeleteMapping("{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('FB_UI_TRUSTED_CERTS_DELETE')")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> .....
```

but I get an AccessDeniedException.

If i change the method @PreAuthorize to test for an authority earlier in the list of auths, it works (the user is allowed to perform the function).

I can see some great resources on Jwt Auth in SS6 but I am not sure what to do to this to apply (e.g. do I need a JwtDecoder etc). I am guessing that if I can parse the jwt, I can use it.  Any thoughts very much welcome.

My SecurityConfig:

```
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableMethodSecurity
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private JwtSettings settings;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain apiSecurityfilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        return http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .cors(corsCustomizer ->corsCustomizer.configurationSource(request -> {
                    CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration  = new CorsConfiguration();
                    corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:9080"));
                    corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                    corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
                    corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));
                    corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("Content-Disposition");
                    corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers");
                    corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers");
                    corsConfiguration.addExposedHeader("Content-Disposition");
                    corsConfiguration.setMaxAge(3600L);
                    return corsConfiguration;
                }))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/api/auth/signin", "/api/auth/sso", "/api/version/*")
                            .permitAll()
                            .anyRequest()
                            .authenticated();
                })
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(settings),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                )
                .build();

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    { return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(); }

}
```

And my JwtAuthenticationFilter ( I hacked out the logging calls for brevity):

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtSettings settings;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {


        final String authHeader = request.getHeader(AUTHENTICATION_HEADER_NAME);
        String jwt = null;

        if (null != authHeader) {
            jwt=request.getHeader(AUTHENTICATION_HEADER_NAME).substring("Bearer ".length());
         
        } 


        if (null != jwt) {

           
            try {
                final Claims claims = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                        .setSigningKey(getSignKey())
                        .build()
                        .parseClaimsJws(jwt)
                        .getBody();

                final String username = String.valueOf(claims.get("sub"));
                final String authorities = String.valueOf(claims.get("permissions"));       
                final Authentication auth =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(authorities));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

            } catch (Exception e) {

               

                throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid token received");
            }
        } 

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private SecretKey getSignKey() {

        final byte[] keyBytes = settings.getTokenSigningKey().getBytes();
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }

}
```

I expected that Method sec should work as before...but it appears that the hasAuthority predicate is returning false for my test user where the auth is the last in the authorities list.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to why you are not using the built in JWT handling that already exists in spring security.

Comment: Thanks for the reply : because I am not sure what that is, in the case I have.  I have been following this https://sergiolema.dev/2023/03/20/spring-security-6-with-jwt-authentication/comment-page-1/ a bit.  I would be more than happy to use Spring Components but the jwt docs I found seemed to be in the context of OAuth which isnt something we do.       If you have any pointers, they would be much appreciated - I havent really had much luck comprehending how to do this from the docs I have found so far.

Comment: AHa I can see what is going amiss.   The first of my authorities starts with [, and the last ends with ].  So the last auth definitely doesnt match and the predicate is correctly returning false.  I am pretty sure I would benefit from having a framework component decode the jwt :)

Comment: `jwt docs I found seemed to be in the context of OAuth which isnt something we do` If you are just going for sessions use session cookies as they are WAY more secure. JWTs are not built to be sessions https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/08/17/why-jwts-suck-as-session-tokens JWTs where not designed to be used as a long lived sessions. You cant logout a JWT, and your JWT can be stolen using XSS. I dont know what you are going for but what you are building is not secure. Dont build custom security https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/JSON_Web_Token_for_Java_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: that's great advice...we're just a REST app so no session.   We do have some security advice along the lines you suggest and a JIRA for it :)